# Objective C setter in superclass called instead of subclass

Tags: objective-c, overriding, nsnull

I am trying to subclass UILabel so the setter setText check for null to avoid this if the supplied parameter is a NSNULL:
    [NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

The code is as below. I stepped through in a debugger and it didn't go into the new setter which I called by:

```
    [someSubClassLabel setText:someValueWhichMayBeNull];
```

where someSubClassLabel is a UILabelWithNULLHandler.

in the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UILabelWithNULLHandler : UILabel
- (void) setText:(NSString *) newText;
@end
```

Defined the method in the .m:

```
- (void) setText:(NSString *) newText
{
    if(![newText isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        super.text = newText;
    }
    else
    {
        super.text = @"";
    }
}
```

Edit:
I suppose I can add code to handle nil, but for the time being, I am dealing with NSNUll which I pulled from a NSDictionary.

Comment: Are you sure isKindOfClass is necessary? Why not:

if(newText){ // Do sth 
...

Comment: And `someSubClassLabel` is an instance of `UILabelWithNULLHandler`?

Comment: Are you sure the type of of `someSubClassLabel` is your new `UILabelWithNULLHandler`?

Comment: Since you are overriding a method I think you don't need to define it again in the header file. But I don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: My money's on forgetting to make the label use the new class.  If you're using a NIB you need to edit the nib to change the class of the label.  Simply changing the class of the property is not sufficient.

Comment: Doesn't address the problem, but you can simplify the test to `newText != [NSNull null]`.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks. I am using storyboard though, but will see if that also need changing like a NIB.

Comment: I've never mucked with storyboards, but I'm reasonably certain that would need changing too.

Comment: Yeah, the storyboard is definitely just like a NIB in that regard (how else would it know what class you want the label to be?) A quick test of your null test show it should work. You could also consider a class extension to NSDictionary and make a objectForKeyNotNull method that returns nil or @"" instead of the NSNull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hot Licks was right. I still have a UILabel in my storyboard. Need to set the new class name in the Identity Inspector under Custom Class.